# How to install wireshark by yum but depend libpcap which is build install

Tags: wireshark, yum, libpcap

I have build install libpcap 1.7.4.

Now I want to install wireshark by yum, but it prompt need dependence libpcap 1.4.0.

[The install info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUAcs.jpg)

how can I install wireshark by yum, but use the dependence libpcap 1.7.4 which build installed by myself.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can't.  The Wireshark in the CentOS repository is dynamically linked to the libpcap from the libpcap package.  The wireshark binary knows what to search for (my wireshark is compiled as wireshark-gtk):

```
$ readelf -d /usr/bin/wireshark-gtk | grep libpcap
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpcap.so.1]
```

It will search the dynamic library path for `libpcap.so.1`.  `yum` knows about it (because the packagers were careful when making the RPMs) and will not allow you to install wireshark without installing that lib.  Whatever you compiled by yourself is irrelevant, the responsible packagers have not seen it and therefore `yum` will not take it in consideration.

And there is absolutely nothing that can be done about that.  You need to install `libpcap-1.4.0` if you want to install wireshark through `yum`.  Yet, that does not mean you need to **use** `libpcap-1.4.0` when wireshark is running.

#### Hacking it

For testing purposes GNU `ld` (the linker that includes the shared libraries) understands an environment variable called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Paths (directories) in that variable are searched first for shared libraries to load.  Therefore you can do the following:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/compiled/libpcap
$ wireshark
```

Which will load wireshark and while loading into memory the libpcap from the path given instead of the libpcap installed by `yum` (in `/usr/lib`).  Note that you need to ensure that you have a softlink called `libpcap.so.1` that points to `libpcap.so.1.7.4` (the make should have created it).

**Disclaimer**: This may break!  It is a very bad idea to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a production environment (but wireshark isn't a piece of software that is often used in mission critical environments).  You are now depending not on the distro maintainers (who test their packages in the scenario of an up-to-date system) but on the developers of wireshark and of libpcap to be careful in not introducing broken backward compatibility (which often is not tested).

In theory nothing should break because sonames in shared libraries shall be backward compatible.  i.e. `libpcap-1.7.4` should be completely backward compatible with `libpcap-1.4.0`.  But sometimes backward compatibility problems do pop-up.